# Rails routing a path

Tags: ruby-on-rails, ruby, routes

I have a view called `views/admin/slinky_files/new.html.erb` that I am trying to open with the following link:

```
<%= link_to 'Add New Slinky', new_slinky_file_path %>
```

And that gives me an error when i click on the link:

```
Routing Error
uninitialized constant SlinkyFilesController
```

And of course, this is because it should be `Admin::SlinkyFilesController`

How do I fix this? I somehow need to route the `new_slinky_file_path` to instead be something like `admin_new_slinky_file_path` I think?

`rake routes | grep slinky` OUTPUT:

```
              slinkys GET    /slinkys(.:format)                            slinkys#index
                      POST   /slinkys(.:format)                            slinkys#create
           new_slinky GET    /slinkys/new(.:format)                        slinkys#new
          edit_slinky GET    /slinkys/:id/edit(.:format)                   slinkys#edit
               slinky GET    /slinkys/:id(.:format)                        slinkys#show
                      PUT    /slinkys/:id(.:format)                        slinkys#update
                      DELETE /slinkys/:id(.:format)                        slinkys#destroy
         slinky_files GET    /slinky_files(.:format)                       slinky_files#index
                      POST   /slinky_files(.:format)                       slinky_files#create
      new_slinky_file GET    /slinky_files/new(.:format)                   slinky_files#new
     edit_slinky_file GET    /slinky_files/:id/edit(.:format)              slinky_files#edit
          slinky_file GET    /slinky_files/:id(.:format)                   slinky_files#show
                      PUT    /slinky_files/:id(.:format)                   slinky_files#update
                      DELETE /slinky_files/:id(.:format)                   slinky_files#destroy
        admin_slinkys GET    /admin/slinkys(.:format)                      admin/slinkys#index
                      POST   /admin/slinkys(.:format)                      admin/slinkys#create
     new_admin_slinky GET    /admin/slinkys/new(.:format)                  admin/slinkys#new
    edit_admin_slinky GET    /admin/slinkys/:id/edit(.:format)             admin/slinkys#edit
         admin_slinky GET    /admin/slinkys/:id(.:format)                  admin/slinkys#show
                      PUT    /admin/slinkys/:id(.:format)                  admin/slinkys#update
                      DELETE /admin/slinkys/:id(.:format)                  admin/slinkys#destroy
```

Comment: Could you show up your `rake routes` output?

Comment: You have already activated rake 10.0.4, but your Gemfile requires rake 10.0.3. Using bundle exec may solve this.

Comment: `bundle clean` `rake routes`

Comment: Can only use bundle clean when --path is set or --force is set

Comment: my bed, `bundle update`

Comment: What should a route look like to get this working? My rake routes output is REALLY long

Comment: `rake route | grep slinky`

Comment: I have added this output (rake routes | grep slinky)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

template:

```
<%= link_to 'Add New Slinky', new_admin_slinky_file_url %>
```

contoller:

```
class Admin::SlinkyFilesController < ApplicationController
  def new
    @slinky_file = SlinkyFile.new
  end
end
```

routes.rb:

```
scope "admin" do
  resources :silky_files
end
```

Comment: Now I get No route matches [GET] "/admin/slinky_files/new"

Comment: @CodeGuy Please include the relevant `routes.rb` section, and the output of related `rake routes`.

Comment: I already had that controller code. Now I get undefined local variable or method `new_admin_slinky_file_url' for #<#<Class:0x007fa3625ce5d8>:0x007fa368257f48>

Comment: @DaveNewton I'm not sure what's relevant. The output is HUGE

Comment: @ted could you just post what I can add to my routes.rb to get this to work

Comment: I added the output to routes

Comment: undefined local variable or method `new_admin_slinky_file_url

Comment: @CodeGuy, `rake route | grep slinky`, restart app if new routes haven't appreared. `scope "/admin" do` to `namespace` depending on your app route

Comment: the new routes appeared and yes I added the code you updated to my routes.rb. the error is what I posted

Comment: no new routes appeared after restarting application (sorry for the mistypo earlier)

Comment: let us [continue this discussion in chat](http://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/28206/discussion-between-ted-and-codeguy)

Comment: actually, I managed to make some progress. the trick was not include the backslash in the admin in the routes.rb I have a new error now

Comment: @CodeGuy, quite new or related?